# Get the position of an item in a HTML list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know the position an item in HTML list.

```
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
</ul>

$('ul').on("click", function(event){
  var target = event.target;
})
```

So when I get the first `li` as the target of the event. How can I get `0` as result for the item postion. The only way I can think about is to iterate over all items and compare them with the event target, but I wonder if there is a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
$('ul').on("click", function(event){
  var target = event.target,
      index = $(target).index();
  console.log(target, index);
})
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vAnCY/).

Reference:

- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Answer (score 2):

```
var listItem = $(event.target);
alert('Index: ' + $('ul > li').index(listItem));
```

Comment: +1 - I like this answer because it shows that you can pass an argument into the `index` feature.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul li').on("click", function(){
var index = $(this).index();
alert(index);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6QZbT/